# SQL Server case insensitive

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, collation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx

Will this work for all databases or must I manually use on every new database which I will add?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quote from the link you provided, first line reads:

> **The server collation acts as the default collation for all system databases that are installed with the instance of SQL Server, and also any newly created user databases.**

That's assuming the databases being created aren't specifying what collation to use.

A database is a group of objects (tables, functions, etc), which can be from multiple schemas.  The instance is the server application running on the host -- you can have more than one SQL Server instance running on a single host.  Each could have numerous databases with them.

Answer (score 0):

During the installation of SQL Server you specify the default collation - which is used on every database you create. If you newly create a database and want to have a new collation - you have to specify it according to this [documentation-link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176061.aspx) or in the properties-menu of the database. If you already have created a database and need to change the collation of existing columns filled with data you need to perform [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190920.aspx) statement.